# How to center a tcolorbox at a part title at KOMA-script article

Tags: lyx, koma-script, tcolorbox, hebrew

I'm trying to center the part title.
The is the MWE:

```
  % Preview source code

%% LyX 2.3.2-2 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn,english,hebrew,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setlength{\parindent}{0bp}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth

\def\@outputdblcol{%
  \if@firstcolumn
    \global \@firstcolumnfalse
    \global \setbox\@leftcolumn \box\@outputbox
  \else
    \global \@firstcolumntrue
    \setbox\@outputbox \vbox {%
      \hb@xt@\textwidth {%
      \kern\textwidth \kern-\columnwidth %**
      \hb@xt@\columnwidth {%
         \box\@leftcolumn \hss}%
      \kern-\textwidth %**
      \hfil
      {\normalcolor\vrule \@width\columnseprule}%
      \hfil
      \kern-\textwidth  %**
      \hb@xt@\columnwidth {%
         \box\@outputbox \hss}%
      \kern-\columnwidth \kern\textwidth %**
    }%
  }%
  \@combinedblfloats
  \@outputpage
  \begingroup
  \@dblfloatplacement
  \@startdblcolumn
  \@whilesw\if@fcolmade \fi
  {\@outputpage
    \@startdblcolumn}%
  \endgroup
  \fi
}
\@mparswitchtrue

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam Mono CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{Bellefair}

\usepackage{adforn}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\setkomafont{part}{\itshape}
\setkomafont{partnumber}{}
\renewcommand*{\partformat}{חלק~ :\thepart~~}
\renewcommand\partheadmidvskip{}
\renewcommand\partlineswithprefixformat[3]{\hfill\begin{center}\fontsize{20pt}{20pt}\selectfont{\begin{tcolorbox}[center]\underline{\adforn{36} 
            #2#3 \adforn{64}}\end{tcolorbox}}\end{center}\hfill}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand*{\raggedpart}{\centering}}

\makeatother

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}

\part{שלום}
\end{document}
```

And here is the output:
[image]

I tried many commands (as you can see at the MWE) but the box it's still at right.

Do you know how can I move it to the center?

**Important note: When I remove the tcolorbox it's works fine (the title move to the center) - the problem is when I add the color box.**

Comment: This is not a *minimal* working example!

Comment: Why not? It's working and it's minimal...

Comment: I deleted some code....

Comment: I put the code back because it's something that LyX added and I don't like to touch at the code of LyX :-)

Comment: It's fare away from being minimal, e.g., the `\footnoterule` code (and this is nothing LyX has added!) that breaks KOMA-Script is not needed. And I'm almost sure that hebrew and the special fonts are not needed.

Comment: You right! I delete those lines :) I hope now it's minimal...

Comment: No it isn't. See the code in my answer to see what would be minimal. All the unneseccary code refracts from the real problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep it simple:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\renewcommand*{\raggedpart}{\centering}
\renewcommand*{\partformat}{\partname~\thepart\autodot\enskip}
\renewcommand\partlineswithprefixformat[3]{%
  \tcbox{\underline{#2#3}}%
}
%\usepackage{showframe}% to see the page areas
\begin{document}
\part{Testpart}
\end{document}
```

[image: centered part box]

or with `twocolumn` option for the document class:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\renewcommand*{\raggedpart}{\centering}
\renewcommand*{\partformat}{\partname~\thepart\autodot\enskip}
\renewcommand\partlineswithprefixformat[3]{%
  \tcbox{\underline{#2#3}}%
}
%\usepackage{showframe}% to see the page areas
\begin{document}
\twocolumn[\part{Testpart}]
\end{document}
```

But note: This suggestion works only as long as you do not need a line break. And `\twocolumn` always starts a new page.

Comment: Not working for me :( do you know why??

Comment: @heblyx Because you do not keep it simple.

Comment: This is not simple? `\renewcommand\partlineswithprefixformat[3]{\fontsize{20pt}{20pt}\selectfont{\tcbox{\underline{\adforn{36} 
   #2#3 \adforn{64}}}}}`

Comment: I need to add some stuff to the title...

Comment: Can you make my code working with this? Because I trying to figure out where I'm wrong...

Comment: @heblyx You are using `twocolumn`. So the centering is done in the first column. With hebrew this is the right column. `\part` of article classes do respect the columns. You need a report or book class if you want parts on their own pages.

Comment: You right (as usual!) - LyX put it as two columns. I don't know why, but know its works perfect!

Comment: @heblyx You should learn how to use LyX or you should not use it. You almost always have problems because of failing in the correct usage of LyX.

Comment: I know how to use LyX, at this time you right because I copy the design from other file that have a two columns, and I forgot it and I forgot to change it back to one column (so at this time this was my fault), I'm apologize!

Comment: about the _But note_: If I need line break - what I need to do? What I need to add that title will still be centered?